# plotting lists columnwise inside a table using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists which need to be plotted as a table according to their column headers:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    columnheaders=('Question Text', 'Answer Status')
    data_list_1=['hi','name pleas','how are you']
    data_list_2=['answered','notanswered','answered']
    **##the_table=ax.table(cellText=data_list,colLabels=columns,)**
    ax.axis("off")
    the_table.set_fontsize(14)
    the_table.scale(1.5, 1.5)
    plt.show()
```

How do i pass data_list_1 and data_list_2 to the ax.table() function so that i get a table in the following format:

```
Question text           answer status
hi                          answered
name please                 not answered
how are you                 answered
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
columnheaders=['Question Text', 'Answer Status']
data_list_1=['hi','name pleas','how are you']
data_list_2=['answered','notanswered','answered']
l = [data_list_1, data_list_2]
l = list(map(list, zip(*l)))
the_table=plt.table(cellText=l,loc='top', colLabels = columnheaders, cellLoc='center')
plt.axis("off")
the_table.set_fontsize(14)
the_table.scale(2, 7)
plt.show()
```

You need to get the data in right format